# How to find mixed models regression with random intercepts corrected for time (month) as a continuous variable?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models

I am new to mixed models regression and I am trying to figure out how to compute mixed models regression with random intercepts corrected for time (ie, month) as a continuous variable.

[image: The datafram is shown here]

I used:

```
library(lme4) model <- lmer(ACS_Cases ~ COVID_Cases + (COVID_Cases | Month), data = Monthly_ACS_COVID)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
Warning message: Some predictor variables are on very different scales: consider rescaling
```

I was wondering if I coded this correctly and why I received this error message. Also does this regression analysis include random intercepts? Thanks so much!!

Comment: For random intercepts per month, you want `(1 | Month)`. Beyond that, it's difficult to help without a reproducible example, and specifically having a sense as to the structure of your data. Is Month a Date variable, a factor variable, a character variable?

Comment: Month is a yearmon variable from the zoo package